# Jetpack Compose Error on dismissing the Dialog: Anchor refers to a group that was removed

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

With the latest version of Jetpack compose Alpha-12 and Kotlin version 1.4.30. While dismissing a Dialog I'm facing

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Anchor refers to a group that was removed
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SlotTable.anchorIndex(SlotTable.kt:199)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Anchor.toIndexFor(SlotTable.kt:466)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.getCompositionLocalScope$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3124)
```

Comment: The implementation was working fine in jetpack Compose Alpha-11. That's why I did not post any of the code. If someone requires then I can create a sample project and post a link over here

Comment: So the error exactly occurs when I edit a Text field in a Dialog or in a Popup and then dismiss:

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in the latest release of Jetpack compose.

The issue can be tracked here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180818652